# how to create dask-gateway worker nodes in kubernetes with custom image pull secret

Tags: kubernetes, dask

I have installed dask-gateway via the helm chart. I assume that I can provide an options handler in the `gateway.backend.extraConfig` section of the chart values. I would also assume I can then configure any option for [KubeClusterConfig](https://gateway.dask.org/api-server.html#kube-cluster-config).

This will allow me to customize the image. How do I specify an image pull secret?

Answer (score 2):

In fact, `KubeClusterConfig` contains the option `worker_extra_pod_config`, which is a dictionary merged into the pod spec, so `imagePullSecrets` can be specified here.

Comment: One thing to keep in mind is that the version of python and cloudpickle need to be the same in worker and other pods, (or at least, perhaps, the gateway). I added a [PR to be able to build python3.8 based images](https://github.com/dask/dask-gateway/pull/309), and am also going to submit a PR for imagePullSecrets in values for gateway and controller.